# Selecting initial item in ListView to change style

Tags: android, listview

I am using a ListView as a menu where when you select an item, the style changes to show it's selected and the content pane changes.  My problem is that I can't figure out how to "select/change the style" of the first item to show it's the selected item by default.  I'm not performing an item click because this screen is what the user first sees before clicking.  I've tried getListView().getChildAt(0) in onActivityCreated and onStart but it always returns null.  I've also tried calling listView.performItemClick().  Below is the code and you can see my current hack solution in my custom MenuAdapter.  I feel like I'm missing something simple since it seems many apps would want to do this.  Thank you for any help!

```
public class FixItActionListFragment extends ListFragment {
    // The last menu item selected 
    View lastRow = null;

    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

        // Defined the list of actions in the file strings.xml
        String[] fixItActions = getResources().getStringArray(R.array.fixItActions);

        setListAdapter(new MenuAdapter(getActivity(), fixItActions));
    }

    /**
     * Inflate the layout for the action list fragment
     */
    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState) {

        // Inflate the layout for the action list fragment
        View v =  inflater.inflate(R.layout.fixitactionlistfragment, container, false);
        return v;
    }

    @Override
    public void onActivityCreated(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onActivityCreated(savedInstanceState);
                // this isn't working
        //ListView listview = getListView();
        //View view = listview.getAdapter().getView(0, null, null);
        //long rowId = listview.getAdapter().getItemId(0);
        //listview.performItemClick(view, 0, rowId);
    }

    /**
     * Called when a action item is selected
     */
    public void onListItemClick(ListView parent, View view, int position, long id) {
        // Change the style of the selected item and revert the last item
        if (lastRow != null) {
            // Set the previous selected row to unselected  
                        ...
        }
            // Set current item to selected
            ...
        lastRow = view;

    }

    class MenuAdapter extends ArrayAdapter<String> {

        MenuAdapter(Context context, String[] actions) {
            super(context, R.layout.menu_row, R.id.menuItem, actions);
        }

        @Override
        public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
            // Get the selected row
            View row = super.getView(position, convertView, parent);
            // HACK!!!!  If it's the first item, then mark as selected
            if (lastRow == null) {
                lastRow = row;
                TextView thisItem = (TextView) row.findViewById(R.id.menuItem);
                thisItem.setTextColor(getResources().getColor(R.color.menuItemSelected));               
            }
            return row;         
        }
    }
}
```